# html nav menu to wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

I need your help I have nav menu in my html I wanted to get them exactly when I transferred it to Wordpress but when i transferred my html to Wordpress it didn't look the same. Wordpress wasn't able to read my Navbar Menu CSS, why is that? Can you help me?
Kindly see images of what I'm trying to say.

[image: HTML file]

[image: HTML to Wordpress]

Here's my nav menu html code and css:

```css
/* navbar*/
.navbar-default {
   /* navbar  background-color: #F8F8F8;
    background:url(../images/header-bg.png);*/

    background: #16ad99; /* Old browsers */
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #16ad99 0%, #85e2d0 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#16ad99), color-stop(100%,#85e2d0)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #16ad99 0%,#85e2d0 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #16ad99 0%,#85e2d0 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #16ad99 0%,#85e2d0 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right,  #16ad99 0%,#85e2d0 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#16ad99', endColorstr='#85e2d0',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-8 */


    border-color: #93BBEB;
}

/* removing white space between navbar and image below*/
.navbar{
 margin-bottom:0px;

}/* end */



/*===================
   NAV BAR
  ===================*/
 .nav .navbar-nav{
  display:inline;

 }
.nav .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.nav .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.nav .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #000000;
}

/* link */
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #000000;
}



.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a {
 color: #00A36E;
```

```html
<!-- Static Top navbar -->
    <header class="main-header">
     <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
       <div class="container">
         <div class="navbar-header">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".collapse">
             <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           </button>
          
         </div><!--END NAVHEADER-->

         <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
           <?php
            wp_nav_menu(array
             (
              'theme_location' => 'main-menu',
              'container' => '',
              'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav' 

              )

             );

           ?>

         </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
       
       </div><!--END CONTAINER-->
     </div><!--END NAVBAR-->
     </header>
```

```html
<!-- Static Top navbar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
       <div class="container">
         <div class="navbar-header">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".collapse">
             <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           </button>
          
         </div><!--END NAVHEADER-->

         <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
             <li><a href="index.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>
             <li><a href="Portfolio.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></span> Portfolio</a></li>
             <li><a href="Contact.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Contact</a></li>
             
           </ul>

         </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
       
       </div><!--END CONTAINER-->
     </div><!--END NAVBAR-->
```

Answer (score 0):

This nice little php script works GREAT for me.  Especially since it looks like you're using Bootstrap!  This will take your pages and post them in a BS menu with dropdown capabilities.

[**LINK**](https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker)

Add this function to your functions.php file:

```
// Register Custom Navigation Walker
     require_once('wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php');
// Nav Walker
     register_nav_menus( array(
     'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'THEMENAME' ),
     ) );
```

Then you have to install a php file called wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php (included on the website I linked to)

Then in your header.php you can enter something like this:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
       <?php 
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'menu'              => 'primary',
                'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                'depth'             => 2,
                'container'         => '',
                'container_class'   => '',
                'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                );
        ?>

                        <form role="form" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url() ; ?>/">
                            <div class="col-sm-2 input-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" value="<?php echo esc_html($s, 1); ?>" name="s" id="s" maxlength="33" />
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button class="btn btn-search" id="searchsubmit" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                                    </span>
                            </div>
                        </form>

    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>
```

And using the "menus" section in the Dashboard of your WP build, you can create a menu and apply your pages to it.  Real simple to use and very scalable.

Give it a shot!

Comment: I use it in all my WP/BS builds... let me know if you have any trouble implementing it.  It's a great tool.

Answer (score -1):

This is most likely because you are using `wp_nav_menu()` and your original code didn't match up with the HTML generated by `wp_nav_menu()`. Can you post both your original code and the wordpress raw code (the one generated, not the one you input into the template)

Comment: hi! melissa, Kindly see the original nav menu in html(the code below), the middle code was the one I used in Wordpress, same css I use in HTML and Wordpress.

Comment: yes, but what i am trying to say is, the code generated by wp function `wp_nav_menu(array
             (
              'theme_location' => 'main-menu',
              'container' => '',
              'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav' 

              )

             );`
 may not be the same as your original HTML. are you able to provide a JSfiddle? or perhaps link me to the live site?